# Batch: Close executable when batch file is terminated

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file which continuously opens a game if it crashes. Im trying to make it so that if the batch file is closed the program will terminate.

```
@echo off

if "%1" equ "loop" goto %1
start "" /WAIT /B "%~F0" loop 
Taskkill /f /im "Crossy Road.exe" >nul
goto :EOF

:loop
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Crossy Road.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Crossy Road.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" explorer.exe shell:appsFolder\Yodo1Ltd.CrossyRoad_s3s3f300emkze!App
goto loop
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a companion vbs from within a batch script that monitors the cmd.exe process and calls another batch script to end the desired processes. (that companion batch script can also be created from within your main batch program)

```
@ECHO OFF

::: Creates a VBS script to monitor the Cmd Process
:CreateMonitor
(
ECHO Set objWMIService = GetObject ("winmgmts:"^) 'Defines winmgmts service
ECHO Set proc = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process Where Name='cmd.exe'"^) 'Gets Current Process Count
ECHO DO while proc.count ^> 0 'Establishes Loop that ends when no cmd.exe windows or bat programs are open
ECHO Set proc = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process Where Name='cmd.exe'"^) 'Gets Current Process Count
ECHO if proc.count ^< 1 then exit do 'exits while loop once bat program is closed
ECHO wscript.sleep 2500 'Delays loop by 2.5 seconds to reduce CPU usage
ECHO loop 'Returns to get new process Count
ECHO Set WshShell=createobject("wscript.shell"^) 'Creates Shell to
ECHO WshShell.run "INSERT PATH TO TASK-KILL .BAT HERE", 0, false 'Launches hidden .bat to close desired programs
) >"%TEMP%\myprogramMonitor.vbs"

::: Starts the VBS to monitor if cmd.exe is open

Start "" "%TEMP%\myprogramMonitor.vbs"

GOTO :EOF
```

It's also prudent to include a taskill for the WScript process in the companion batch:

`taskkill /pid WScript.exe /f /t >nul`